# Login failed for user DEV\xxx (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008, login

Brand new installation of SQL2008 R2.

My user, xxx, is a domain admin.

I am attempting to connect via management studio while directly logged onto the SQL box.

If I specifically add that user to SQL Logins then I can connect OK.

However, if I add the group DEV\Domain Admins as a login I get the error above. Further, in the SQL log I also see:
Login failed for user DEV\xxx. Reason: Token-based server axxess validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS is this running on? If 2008/2008R2, try running management studio as an admin and try again.